# In Webpack/module environment, Materialize CSS not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, materialize

I have an application perfectly working with MaterializeCSS and jQuery installed via npm

```
"jquery": "^3.5.0",
"materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
```

I'm not using Webpack nor ES6 modules, instead I make a bundle with Gulp and than requiring the file

```
<script src="/script/vendor.min.js"></script>
```

In my code, the istruction

```
$('.sidenav').sidenav();
```

is working fine.

As soon as I go for Webpack and ES6 modules, with exactly the same versions of jQuery and Materialize

```
import $ from "jquery";
import M from 'materialize-css';
```

The instruction

```
$('.sidenav').sidenav();
```

is giving out an error "Undefined function Sidenav".

I tried to switch to Materialize's jQuery-free syntax

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
var instance = new M.Sidenav(elem);
```

and it started working.

I also tried to import Materialize in this way

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js';
```

But nothing changed.
How to have Mterialize working properly with jQuery syntax?

Thank you

Comment: Which version of materialize are you using? Should be 1.0.0. And are you definitely loading jQuery first?

Comment: I am using 1.0.0-rc2. I tried to switch to version 1.0.0 but nothing changed. I check the output JS bundle and Jquery code is placed BEFORE materialize code, so I think it's correcto. What else could I check? Thank you

Comment: Anything in the console..?

Comment: As written on the main post the error in the console is "sidenav not defined"